# OrientDB. Connection re-acquired after automatic backups

Tags: java, orientdb

We have a large mutithreaded java ee application running on Wildfly 8. We are using Orient 2.1.19.
After couple of automatic backups our log files contain a lot of messages like following.

```
11:07:57,739 WARNING [com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote] (default task-104) Caught I/O errors from Not connected (local socket=?), trying to reconnect (error: java.io.EOFException)
11:07:57,747 WARNING [com.orientechnologies.orient.client.remote.OStorageRemote] (default task-104) Connection re-acquired transparently after 6ms and 1 retries to server '127.0.0.1:2424/vis_demo': no errors will be thrown at application level
```

Also CPU usage is very high and all threads named "OrientDB <- Asynch Client (/127.0.0.1:2424)" recreated. At some point  we can see (usinf VisualVM) hundreds of such threads.

Comment: Hi @Nem, these are just warnings no errors

Comment: Hi @MichelaBonizzi, Sure. but recreating of threads causes a high cpu usage. And what should we do with hundreds of threads? Just now application got freezed. And the only way is restart the app

Comment: Investigations show that setting db.setProperty(ORemoteConnectionManager.PARAM_MAX_POOL, 1000); affects the situation. Warnings appear after much more backups.